# How to get only one value from the record in the list in c#?

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have two custom list:

```cs
List<Detailsofemployee> empDetails = new List<Detailsofemployee>();
List<regionDetails> regDetails = new List<regionDetails>();
```

- `empDetails` have values `{"1","Sam","IT"}`.
- `regDetails` have values `{"IT","UK"}`.

I want to get the data from first list and based on that i want to get data from another list

```cs
var det = (from l in empDetails where l.ID == "1" select l.Department)
var region = (from l in regDetails where l.Department == det select l.Country)
```

How can I get `det = "IT"`?

Comment: I don't understand the object `DetailsofEmployee`. I sopose it has three properties: `ID`, `Name` and `Area` no?

Comment: Is the `empDetails` department, the same object type as in 'regDetails'?  they'd have to be exactly the same object for the == to work.  You could try `l.Department.Name.Equals(det.Name)` instead.

Comment: Yes,It has list of data with the properties ID,NAME,DEPARTMENT
and regDetails have properties DEPARTMENT,COUNTRY

Answer (score 0):

with checking and user input value

```
using System.Linq;

var userInputId = //user input value
var emp = empDetails.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == userInputId);
var regDetail = new regionDetails();
if (emp != null)
{
   regDetail =  regDetails.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Department == emp.Department);
}
if (regDetail != null)
{
    return regDetail.Country;
}
```